# Is it possible to have fully working sourcemaps to debug minified CSS generated from SASS using Gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp, source-maps, building, gulp-sourcemaps

Using Gulp, I am able to produce CSS transpiled from SASS with sourcemaps that point to the original SASS files, and I am also able to produce sourcemaps to debug minified CSS, but so far I have been unable to work out how (if it is even possible) to produce sourcemaps using Gulp that allow you to debug CSS that is both transpiled from SASS **and** minified, along with adding vendor prefixes etc. I have managed to produce some sourcemap outputs but they end up mapping back to the wrong line in the .scss files when I perform both transpilation and minification.

This code below does produce sourcemaps as an output which the browser picks up and reads, but as I said before, Chrome debug tools point to the wrong files/lines in the original .scss files.

Here is my css-compile Gulp task.

```html
// compile SASS

'use strict';

var gulp    = require('gulp'),
 gutil    = require('gulp-util'),
 plugins   = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
 browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
 config    = require('../config/css-compile.json'),
 isStaging   = true,
 isProduction  = false;

gulp.task(config.taskName, function () {
 return gulp.src(config.dirs.src)
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(plugins.sass(config.sass,{sourcemap: true}).on('error', plugins.sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dirs.dest))
        .pipe(plugins.minifyCss({map: true}))
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dirs.dest));
});
```

Comment: What happens when you write the sourcemaps before you minify? Because right now, it looks like you're minifying twice.